# Use 'disable' attribute in modelformset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using a modelformset to change multiple records at once.

I started with a simple formset and a form:

**forms.py**

```
class SetupForm(forms.Form):
    student_id = forms.IntegerField(disabled=True)
    student_firstname = forms.CharField(label = _("First Name"))
    student_lastname = forms.CharField(label=_("Last Name"))
```

Using the new 'disabled' attribute was simple. Now I changed to a modelformset for convenience but I have issues activating the same attribute.

My ModelFormset:

**views.py**

```
def setup_student(request):

    StudentFormSet = modelformset_factory(Student,
                                    fields=('student_id', 'student_firstname', 'student_lastname',), extra=0)

    participant_formset = KTNFormSet(queryset=Student.objects.all())
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your formset like this:

```
StudentFormSet = modelformset_factory(Student, form=SetupForm, extra=0)
```